# How to overcome ImportError with rpy2 2.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: rpy2

I'm stuck getting rpy2 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.  I have python version 2.7.6 and ran

> sudo pip install rpy2

which seemed successful.

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rpy2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): singledispatch in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.7.egg (from rpy2)
Building wheels for collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rpy2
  Stored in directory: /home/xxxxx/.cache/pip/wheels/7e/c7/b8/71c07d811319f897a43c9803d5cd890c66f4d18c3b6aa03e11
Successfully built rpy2
Installing collected packages: rpy2
Successfully installed rpy2-2.6.1
```

However when I tried a test

> python -m rpy2.tests

the results aren't promising:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/tests.py", line 23, in <module>
    import rpy2.tests_rpy_classic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/tests_rpy_classic.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rpy2.rpy_classic as rpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rpy_classic.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as ri
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so: undefined symbol: Rf_allocVector3
```

I've googled this error but can't find anything referring to Rf_allocVector3

The version of R I'm running is 3.0.2, in case that has an impact.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R version is too old for rpy2-2.6.0, I think.

The documentation lets one hope that R-3.0.x is OK but I think that it is not the case: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.6/html/overview.html#requirements